# Create multipage pdf from screenshot/bitmap bitmap android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, bitmap

I have a layout that shows invoices and I take screenshots of that screen and convert them into pdf.
Here is a screenshot of the invoice image/pdf: [image: here]

pdf screen : [[image: pdf]][2]]

It seems to be a perfect invoice pdf but the problem is when items on the list will be increase layout will be minimized to fit perfectly. In a simple way, it h,aofnly oIe page of pdf.

**Help me: Divide this screenshot into two parts and put both different screenshot to different pages of pdf**
Logic:
First off all i set invoice screenshot one layout and then i take screen shot and then i convert into pdf

java code

```
private fun takeScreenShot() {
        /*ScreenShot Code*/
        root = findViewById(R.id.main)
        root.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        )
        root.layout(0, 0, root.measuredWidth, root.measuredHeight)
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.width, root.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(bitmap)
        root.draw(c)

        /*ScreenShot Image Visibility Set */
        layoutBinding.rootViewLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        layoutBinding.invoiceImv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        layoutBinding.toolbarLayout.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        layoutBinding.rootViewInvoiceImageLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        generatePDF()
    }

private fun generatePDF() {
        Log.i(TAG + INVOICE_TEMPLATE1, "generatePDF")
        try {
            val document = PdfDocument()
            val pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo =
                PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, 1).create()
            val page: PdfDocument.Page = document.startPage(pageInfo)

            val canvas: Canvas = page.canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
            document.finishPage(page)

            val directoryPath: String = this.getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.path + "/" + id + ".pdf"
            myFile = File(directoryPath)
            document.writeTo(FileOutputStream(myFile))
            document.close()
            closeLoader()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.i(TAG + INVOICE_TEMPLATE1, "setData --> Exception --> ${ex.printStackTrace()}")
        }
    }
```

so what i need is i want to divide this screenshot into two image and then make one page pdf to multipage pdf

If anyone can help please help me out and anyone have any doubt please comment below down.

Comment: My guess is that you will be better served using a PDF generation library (iText or commercial ones). That being said, to have multiple pages, you need to call `startPage()`, draw, and then `finishPage()` for each page. We cannot help you with the drawing part, because we do not know how you are creating `root`.

Comment: Okay Thank you using this library i'll make multipage pdf but what's about image i want to divide image in to two parts to set that both image to multi page pdf if you anythink about please help me out.

Comment: That will be a complex bit of business logic. A well-crafted multi-page invoice will not simply have a page break in the middle of it. It will have the header (your Jerry image, Mujammil, invoice number, etc.) on each page, as well as the column headings. We cannot really help you with that. Partly, it is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. Partly, we do not know how you are creating your current single-page `View`, as that code lies outside of your question, perhaps because it is very complex.

Comment: But, in the end, you need to create a `View` that represents page 1, a `View` that represents page 2, etc. And then you need to render each to the PDF `Canvas`. Note that you should be able to eliminate `Bitmap.createBitmap()` to save memory. Also, it may be possible to use just one `View` and tell it which range of rows to show, then use that `View` multiple times to create each page.

Comment: Without seeing how you create the layout it is hard, I create multi page pdf tables by creating a TableLayout programmatic and keeping track of the `TableRow` items measured heights as each row is added, so I can create a new pdf page when the table gets too long. (You do also have to be careful of the width as well).

Comment: Should i embed xml layout?

Comment: @Andrew I'll try as you said. Thank you